# ParseQueryAdapter for ListFragment

Tags: android, parse-platform

As [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) is meant to be used with an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) - what is the general design idea for using a [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) for a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)?  I want to display a custom list view.

I've tried to use a [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html) with a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html), but the images are not displayed properly.  If I use the exact code with an [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), the images load correctly.

How can you use a [ParseQueryAdapter](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQueryAdapter.html)in conjunction with a [ListFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html)?

I've posted the general code, but the text from the query loads wonderfully in the list, the images however don't always load or when they do..take a LONG time to show up.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<ListView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0px"
    />

</RelativeLayout>

public class PlacesTab extends ListFragment {
...
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.places_tab, container, false);

    mainAdapter = new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity(), “Places”);
    mainAdapter.setTextKey("name");
    mainAdapter.setImageKey(“placeImage");

    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(mainAdapter);
    mainAdapter.loadObjects();

    return rootView;
}
}//end class
```

Comment: "As ParseQueryAdapter is meant to be used with an Activity" Where did you get this information?

Comment: "I've tried to use a ParseQueryAdapter with a ListFragment" Please show some code that illustrates what you have tried.

Comment: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide Everything on the documentation references an Activity. "To use a ParseQueryAdapter to display data in an Activity, follow the steps outlined below in your Activity's onCreate..."

Comment: You can easily replace "Activity" with "Fragment" and "onCreate()" with "onCreateView()". I don't see anything in the docs that is specific to an Activity.

Comment: Updated with code - This is a Tabbed layout (3-tabs) and when you click an item in the list, it goes to details (Master Detail). Perhaps the complex UI is the problem?

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Has anyone done a tabbed fragmented Parse app before with image loading and custom cells?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips on improving your question to attract the answers you are looking for.